# Create transaction in GnuCash in response to an email?

Tags: python, gnucash

I would like to create a script which is triggered by an email filter which, when run, creates two transactions in GnuCash. I see that [GnuCash has Python bindings](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Python_Bindings) but the documentation is sparse at best... a better term would be "nonexistent".

Is it possible to write a script which will create transactions in GnuCash? If so, what would the very basic code look like? I just need a starting point; once I have that I can script this fairly well myself.

Comment: http://svn.gnucash.org/trac/browser/gnucash/trunk/src/optional/python-bindings/example_scripts/simple_test.py

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative solution using piecash (https://github.com/sdementen/piecash, version 0.10.1), a modern python library to work with gnucash books (**disclaimer**: I am the author)

```
from piecash import open_book, Transaction, Split
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

# open the book
with open_book("/path/to/file.gnucash", 
               open_if_lock=True, 
               readonly=False) as mybook:
    today = datetime.now()
    # retrieve the currency from the book
    USD = mybook.currencies(mnemonic="USD")
    # define the amount as Decimal
    amount = Decimal("25.35")
    # retrieve accounts
    to_account = mybook.accounts(fullname="Expenses:Some Expense Account")
    from_account = mybook.accounts(fullname="Assets:Current Assets:Checking")
    # create the transaction with its two splits
    Transaction(
        post_date=today,
        enter_date=today,
        currency=USD,
        description="Transaction Description!",
        splits=[
            Split(account=to_account,
                  value=amount,
                  memo="Split Memo!"),
            Split(account=from_account,
                  value=-amount,
                  memo="Other Split Memo!"),
        ]
    )
    # save the book
    mybook.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a template, along with a couple of account lookup functions which are sorely lacking in the library.  You can place all of the transaction code into a function, then hand in whatever data you need to create the two custom transactions.  Then just call the transaction function from your email listener, and you should be in business.

```
from gnucash import Session, Account, Transaction, Split, GncNumeric
import gnucash
from datetime import datetime

def lookup_account_by_path(parent, path):
    acc = parent.lookup_by_name(path[0])
    if acc.get_instance() == None:
        raise Exception('Account path {} not found'.format(':'.join(path)))
    if len(path) > 1:
        return lookup_account_by_path(acc, path[1:])
    return acc

def lookup_account(root, name):
    path = name.split(':')
    return lookup_account_by_path(root, path)

session = Session("/path/to/file.gnucash") #, ignore_lock=True)
   # or use URI string: ('mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE')

today = datetime.now()
book = session.book # All actions are performed through the book object (or its children)
root = book.get_root_account() # Parent of all accounts
currency = book.get_table().lookup('ISO4217', "USD")
tx = Transaction(book)
tx.BeginEdit()
tx.SetCurrency(currency)
tx.SetDateEnteredTS(today)
tx.SetDatePostedTS(today) # or another datetime object for the transaction's "register date"
tx.SetDescription("Transaction Description!")
#tx.SetNum(int_variable) # if you need a transaction number

sp1 = Split(book) # First half of transaction
sp1.SetParent(tx)
# The lookup string needs to match your account path exactly.
sp1.SetAccount(lookup_account(root, "Expenses:Some Expense Account"))
# amount is an int (no $ or .), so $5.23 becomes amount=523
sp1.SetValue(GncNumeric(amount, 100)) # Assuming you only have one split
# For multiple splits, you need to make sure the totals all balance out.
sp1.SetAmount(GncNumeric(amount, 100))
sp1.SetMemo("Split Memo!") # optional

sp2 = Split(book) # Need a balancing split
sp2.SetParent(tx)
sp2.SetAccount(lookup_account(root, "Assets:Current Assets:Checking"))
sp2.SetValue(sp1.GetValue().neg())
sp2.SetAmount(sp1.GetValue().neg())
sp2.SetMemo("Other Split Memo!") # optional

tx.CommitEdit() # Finish editing transaction
session.save()
session.end()
```

Comment: s1 should read sp1  This works well for me with gnucash 2.6.7